# OpenPop: "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, openpop

We have a windows service that uses OpenPop to check an email account and process some email on a regular basis.  We've been using it for years and had zero issues. This weekend we moved to a new server (with upgraded Windows Server 2016) and suddenly this service is reporting the error: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

We do use a secure connection to the mail server (Outlook) and I've tried to set the SecurityProtocol as seen on other SO threads and no luck:

```
            Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                client.Connect(this.MailServer, popport, popsecure);
                client.Authenticate(this.MailUN, this.MailPW);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Debug("Cannot connect to POP: " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }
```

I'm not even sure what's going on, let alone know what to do next to debug it. And the service still runs fine still on the old server, but I can't run it there much longer.

Comment: sounds like the new mail server i rejecting your connection

Comment: Either the version of SSL has changed or the Proxy Server is having an issue.  To access the mail server there is also a Proxy Server.  It is possible the new windows server is not connecting to the proxy server.

Comment: The mail server is the same and hasn't changed.  The only thing that has changed is the windows server running the service.